# How to implement if else condition in nginx configuration file through arguments

Tags: nginx

My url is https://www.example.com/article_slug?amp=1 (for amp pages) and for website url is https://www.example.com/article_slug

How can i implement if else condition in server configuration file according to "?amp=1" through URL.

Please help me

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's [better](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) to use [map module](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) than `if` statements in nginx configuration. For example:

```
map $arg_amp $x {
    1        foo;
    2        bar;
    default  baz;
}

...

location / {
    add_header X-Foo $x;
    return 204;
}
```